# Can not retrieve location name from instagram api users/self/feed response

Tags: location, instagram, instagram-api

I have problem with Instagram api.

When I retrieve answer from users/self/feed, I receive list of posts, and I noticed one strange thing.

I try to get location name from post.

If post has location field, we can get location name only if location has latitude and longitude.

```
"location": {
    "latitude": 63.432160153,
    "name": "Ullådalen, Åre",
    "longitude": 12.998837661,
    "id": 244305182
  },
```

If location hasn't latitude and longitude, we can have only location id, and make request to locations/{location-id} for retrieving name, and we'll get  location name.

```
"location": {
    "id": 619070998
  },
```

I don't want to use second query to get location name in case when latitude and longitude are absent.

Is it really? Can we use one query for retrieving all data?